# Change image for NSButton with Swift code

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsbutton

I am running Xcode 7.2.1 and I am using storyboards. I added an "Image Button" to my storyboard and set the image in the attributes inspector. I then created an outlet and action for the button in my code.

When I press the button I want its image to change. In Swift for iOS I would do this:

```
myButtonOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "Pressed-Button-Graphic@2x.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

I tried this for OS X Swift:

```
myButtonOutlet.image(NSImage(named: "Pressed-Button-Graphic@2x.png"))
```

How can I change the image of my button from Swift (OS X)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `image` property on NSImage like this:

```
myButton.image = NSImage(named: "Pressed-Button_Graphic@2x.png")
```

Unlike iOS it doesn't need to use `setImage()` method

Comment: I keep getting the error for this solution: "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'NSImage.Name". 
I've resolved this by doing: myButton.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("Filename"))
iOS uses this: myButton.image = UIImage(named: "Filename.png")

Answer (score 1):

The method by @brimstone did not work for me on **macOS**. I'm running **Swift 4**.

If you have your images added to Assets.xcassets, then this should work (no file extension!):

```
myButton.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("Pressed-Button_Graphic@2x"))
```

And if you just have the images imported to your main folder, then use file extension with the file name.

p.s. For **iOS** use:

```
button.image = UIImage(named: "Picture.png")
```

Comment: It's because probably you are not using xcassets, just pure images.